# Why my JavaFX ImageView is not showing/hiding using the Fade Transition?

Tags: javafx, imageview, fade, transition

I m trying to add a fade transition to my login and logout ImageViews, I tried to use the same pattern as the JFeonix Hamburger, I also used some tutorial at oracle docs but, there is no fade transition my ImageViews are hiding and showing instantly. What I'm missing ?

below is my code :

```
@FXML
    private JFXHamburger menu;
    @FXML
    private ImageView login;
    @FXML
    private ImageView logout;

    private LoginLogic logic;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
        final HamburgerSlideCloseTransition slideCloseTransition = new HamburgerSlideCloseTransition(menu);
        slideCloseTransition.setRate(-1);

        FadeTransition t = new FadeTransition(new Duration(3000), login);
        FadeTransition t1 = new FadeTransition(new Duration(3000), logout);

        t.setCycleCount(1);
        t1.setCycleCount(1);

        t.setAutoReverse(false);
        t1.setAutoReverse(false);

        t.setRate(-1);
        t1.setRate(-1);

        menu.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, (MouseEvent event) -> {
            t1.setRate(t1.getRate() * -1);
            t.setRate(t.getRate() * -1);
            slideCloseTransition.setRate(slideCloseTransition.getRate() * -1);
            slideCloseTransition.play();
            t.play();
            t1.play();
            login.setVisible(!login.isVisible());
            logout.setVisible(!logout.isVisible());
        });
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not changing the look of the node with the `FadeTransition`, since you're still using the default values for `fromValue`, `toValue` and `byValue`.

This means effectively you simply toggle the visibility on and off...

Usually only the opacity is modified by a `FadeTransition`.

#### Example:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button("fade in/out");

    ImageView image = new ImageView("https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png");
    image.setOpacity(0);

    VBox root = new VBox(10, btn, image);
    root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

    FadeTransition t = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(3), image);
    t.setCycleCount(1);
    t.setAutoReverse(false);
    t.setRate(-1);
    t.setFromValue(0);
    t.setToValue(1);

    btn.setOnAction(evt -> {
        t.setRate(t.getRate() * -1);
        t.play();
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```